# Gulp typescript task can't find angular2 modules, compiles fine nonetheless

Tags: angular, typescript, gulp

I'm getting these annoying "false" errors in my gulp output:

```
$ gulp build-ts
[19:30:09] Using gulpfile ~/Learning/vision-boilerplate/gulpfile.js
[19:30:09] Starting 'build-ts'...
[19:30:09] Finished 'build-ts' after 6.33 ms
ng/app.component.ts(1,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
ng/app.component.ts(6,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.
ng/app.module.ts(1,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
ng/app.module.ts(2,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser'.
ng/app.module.ts(3,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/common'.
ng/app.module.ts(4,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
ng/app.module.ts(5,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/http'.
ng/app.routes.ts(1,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
ng/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts(1,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
ng/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts(7,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.
ng/dashboard/dashboard.module.ts(1,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
ng/dashboard/dashboard.module.ts(2,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/common'.
ng/dashboard/dashboard.module.ts(4,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
ng/dashboard/dashboard.routes.ts(1,23): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
ng/input/input-module/input-module.component.ts(1,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
ng/input/input-module/input-module.component.ts(2,23): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
ng/input/input-module/input-module.component.ts(11,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.
ng/input/input-module/input-module.service.ts(1,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
ng/input/input-module/input-module.service.ts(2,47): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/http'.
ng/input/input-module/input-module.service.ts(3,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Rx'.
ng/input/input.component.ts(1,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
ng/input/input.component.ts(2,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
ng/input/input.component.ts(9,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.
ng/input/input.module.ts(1,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
ng/input/input.module.ts(2,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/common'.
ng/input/input.routes.ts(1,23): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
ng/input/input.service.ts(1,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
ng/input/input.service.ts(2,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/http'.
ng/input/input.service.ts(16,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ng/main.ts(1,40): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'.
ng/shared/navbar/navbar.component.ts(1,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
ng/shared/navbar/navbar.component.ts(7,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.
ng/shared/shared.module.ts(1,47): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
ng/shared/shared.module.ts(2,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/common'.
ng/shared/shared.module.ts(3,29): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms'.
ng/shared/shared.module.ts(4,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
[19:30:10] TypeScript: 36 semantic errors
[19:30:10] TypeScript: emit succeeded (with errors)
```

My app actually compiles and works fine, but I really want to get rid of these errors. This is my `build-ts` task:

```
gulp.task('build-ts', function() {
    var result = gulp.src(appDev + '**/*.ts')
        .pipe(inlineNg2Template({useRelativePaths: true}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(typescript(tsProject))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(appProd));
});
```

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
$ cat tsconfig.json 
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "./web/app"
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "./ng/**/*.ts",
    "!./node_modules/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ],
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": true
  }
}
```

My project tree looks like this:

```
$ tree -L 1
.
├── config
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── gulpfile.js
├── ng
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── requirements.txt
├── run.py
├── tsconfig.json
├── typings
├── typings.json
├── vision_modules
└── web
```

All angular2 dependencies should be in `node_modules`. Like I said, the app actually fully behaves as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the typings for typescript. I load them in **main.ts** 
`/// <reference path="../../typings/index.d.ts" />`

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't change anything

Comment: Works for me. Make sure you reference the correct path of you `index.d.ts`.